# Filter() in-place without duplicating formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider a very basic table:

```
List 1 | List 2
a|a
b|c
c|
```

Now I want to produce an array of the intersection of these lists, which is {a,c}.

If I do this:

```
=INDEX(Table1[List2],XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2]))
```

I get:

```
a
#N/A
c
```

Now, to get rid of the #N/A, the only way I found to do it was to essentially repeat the equation, like this:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(Table1[List2],XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2])),NOT(ISNA(INDEX(Table1[List2],XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2])))))
```

which works, but is very non-ideal, as the probability of keeping both versions of the equation in sync is very low.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) to avoid the repeat:

```
=LET(x,INDEX(Table1[List2],XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2])),FILTER(x,NOT(ISNA(x))))
```

However this might be simpler:

```
=FILTER(Table1[List1],ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2])))
```